# How to convert DocumentTermMatrix (tm package) to sparse matrix in R?

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, tm

I used `tm` package and `DocumentTermMatrix` to create a `DocumentTermMatrix` and now I'd like to convert it to spare matrix for an ouput to `glmnet` function from `glmnet` package.

Any idea on how to do this?
The objects looks like this:

```
> str(yy)
List of 6
 $ i       : int [1:13864810] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ j       : int [1:13864810] 320 334 339 346 347 348 355 360 362 363 ...
 $ v       : num [1:13864810] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ nrow    : int 709678
 $ ncol    : int 371
 $ dimnames:List of 2
  ..$ Docs : chr [1:709678] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ Terms: chr [1:371] "declarative_" "declarative_0" "declarative_0zc" "declarative_0zd" ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "DocumentTermMatrix" "simple_triplet_matrix"
 - attr(*, "weighting")= chr [1:2] "term frequency" "tf"
> class(yy)
[1] "DocumentTermMatrix"    "simple_triplet_matrix"
```

Is this the only way?

```
sparseYY <- sparseMatrix( i = yy$i, j=yy$j, x =yy$v)
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply use `as.matrix` to convert to a **sparse matrix**:

```
> dtm_matrix <- as.matrix(dtm)
> class(dtm_matrix)
[1] "matrix"
```